# Xcode C++ debugging

Tags: c++, xcode, ios

I'm looking for a way to have the Xcode IDE pick up on the contents of my weird Boost template classes.  Basically, classes complex enough that Xcode can't display their contents correctly.

Is there something like the Objective C -description method or toString() in Java that Xcode will look for?

At the moment I'm just implementing print() methods and invoking them in gdb, but that's likely to confuse other developers.

Comment: hopefully LLDB will help improve the c++ debugging experience in Xcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try making [Custom Data Formatters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/220-Viewing_Variables_and_Memory/variables_and_memory.html) for your types and the Xcode debugger will use them.

Comment: It's not 100%, but this was definitely in the right direction.  I ended up writing methods called debugString() that returned NSString objects (which are leaked, but never mind).  I then display these with a formatter like so:  {$VAR.debugString()}:s       Ideally, I'd like to plug into something existing so my users wouldn't have to do this manually, but this is simple enough I can explain it.  Doesn't work with std::vector<> for some reason, but that's another problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Some followup, in case anyone runs across this.  In the end, the solution is only somewhat functional.  Xcode seems to have some issues with data formatters.  The popup display is only functional about half the time and seems to require the regular variable display come up first.  This doesn't work with vectors at all, even though Xcode is correctly identifying the type.  All in all, a mediocre implementation.  Hopefully they'll do better in the next version.